# Program to continually ask for double values, using sentinel-controlled loop

Tags: java, exception, sentinel, inputmismatchexception, arraystoreexception

So I am working on a Java program that continually ask the user for double values. I am supposed to use a sentinel-controlled loop with sentinel value of -999. I need to use an ArrayList while using try/catch block to handle inputMismatchExceptions, ArrayStoreExeptions, and general Exceptions.

I am currently having trouble trying to finish the program after entering -999, applying message of a duplicate message from ArrayStoreExceptions and to continue input after inputMismatchExceptions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d;
        double average;
        double max;
        double min;

        ArrayList<Double> value = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a double value (-999 to exit):");
        d = input.nextDouble();

        while (!value.equals(-999)) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a double value (-999 to exit):");
            value.add(input.nextDouble());


        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid double value.");

        } catch (ArrayStoreException e) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate value");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: an arraylist is never going to equal a double, maybe you want to test against the inputted value?

Comment: If you want to request _multiple_ inputs until -999 is entered, you're going to need to request input **inside the loop** as well as, or instead of, just _before_   the loop.

Comment: is there a sample you can give to give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using

```
value.equals(-999)
```

but value is an `ArrayList<Double>` while -999 is just a `double` (an int, actually).
You don't want to check if the whole list equals -999, you just want to check if the last inputted value was -999.

2. If you don't want to allow duplicates, you should be using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html), not an `ArrayList`.
3. When you get an InputMismatchException, you need to call in.nextLine() before asking the user for another double. This is because, if you don't call in.nextLine(), your scanner will still be trying to read the same text that caused the exception the previous time.

Here is a (heavily modified) alteration of your code that should work as you intend it to:
(You may want to use a different implementation of `Set`, depending on your needs).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 0.0; //d is set to some unused starting value so it will compile.
        double average;
        double max;
        double min;

        Set<Double> values = new HashSet<Double>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter a double value (-999 to exit):");
                d = input.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid double value.");
                input.nextLine();
                continue;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                break;
            }
            if(d == -999.)
                break;
            else if(!values.add(d))
                System.out.println("Duplicate value");
        }
        //System.out.println(values);
    }
```

I would also recommend you rename "value" to "values" to make it clear that it represents multiple values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to use an ArrayList as part of an assignment but thanks, I should be able to use it as a template to help me figure it out

Comment: So I managed to get the program to end when entering -999 and to send error message if putting non double value but now I just need to figure out how to detect a duplicate value using the ArrayStoreException